# How can I find the Cauchy Principal Value of this integral using complex analysis?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

[image]

I'm supposed to solve the real integral using a contour integral (The Cauchy Principal Value). Can someone give me a hand? I cannot seem to be able to do it...

This is what I've tried so far:

- I tried computing the contour integral first using the Residue theorem. I simplified the total residue to :$$-\cos(\pi a) - i\sin(\pi a)$$
- I also tried showing that the part of the integral that doesn't lie on the real line goes to zero as $R$ goes to infinity. (where $R$ is the bound on the integral). I tried using the ML equality in combination with the triangle equality to no avail.

Thank you.

Comment: There should only be one residue inside the contour, located at $\pi i$. There are more residues, but they are neither inside the contour nor on the contour, so we don't care about them.

Comment: @Ian Yes, of course! Thank you!

Comment: Jordan's Lemma will probably prove helpful in estimating some of the rest of the contour contributions. Also, I don't think you should expect the rest of the contour contributions to all go to zero. This is actually atypical, and really only occurs when your integrand has very nice decay. But if the other contributions can be expressed in a simple form or in terms of the desired integral (a common case is that one piece is a particular number times the desired integral, for example), then you can still work it out.

Comment: why is there a principal value? $1+e^x>0$ on the complete real line, so no need for that, or am i missing something?

Comment: "contour integral" $\ne$ "cauchy principal value".  Please understand what you are saying before trying to solve the problem.

Comment: @RonGordon I never said their the same thing. I said the cauchy principal value can be found using the contour integral. My exact words were: "solve the real integral using a contour integral (The Cauchy Principal Value)". The sentence in parentheses refers to the solution of the real integral, not the contour integral.

Comment: 1) Not my fault if you were not being clear, 2) even if you were, you are still using the term wrong.  The real integral exists and is finite, so that talk of the Cauchy PV is irrelevant.  I also guarantee you that this problem exists on this site (sans C.P.V.) and you'll find a solution there.

Comment: @RonGordon 1) My sentence was clear. Even if you did find it ambiguous, the rest of the post makes it obvious I know what I'm talking about. 2)Yes, the real integral exists and is finite, but the question specifically asks for the CPV. The question specifically asks to find it using a contour. Please read the question before commenting.

Comment: Their is no principal value to calculate. The question makes no sense the way it is posted. For calculating a principal value you need a discontinuity of oerder one inside your range of integration. This would be the case for example if you replace $1+e^x$ by $1-e^x$

Comment: Last comment.  The reader is the judge of what is clear - the parenthesis implies you were equating the terms.  But that's not important now.  The concept of the CPV **does not apply here**.  For the CPV to apply, there must be a pole on the contour.  Technically, in this case, the CPV is simply the integral anyway, but inserting it into the conversation implies that you do not know what you are talking about.  If you lifted that from a book, then I feel bad you're using a bad book.

Comment: what's the name of the book by the way?

Comment: @RonGordon Fair enough, I should be have been clearer, sorry. Why wouldn't the CPV apply here? Isn't it just equal to the integral since their is no pole (technically speaking)?

Comment: @tired The books name is "Advanced Engineering Mathematics". Question 35, page 879.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After we have agreed that this is just an ordinary integral, the rest is not tough:

Let's denote the four paths by $I_1,I_2,I_3,I_4$ where $I_1$ corresponds to the integral in question, $I_2, I_4$ are the parts parallel to the imaginary axis and $I_3$ is the horizontal one which passes $z=2\pi i$. 
Using the contour above, we easily see that the horizontal parts only differ by phase so $$
I_3=-e^{2\pi a i}I_1
$$

Furthermore it's easy to show that $I_2,I_4$ are vanishing in the limit $|r|\rightarrow\infty$. We can also easily check that there is only one residue at $z=\pi i$ inside the contour. We can conclude that

$$
I_1-e^{2\pi a i}I_1=2\pi i Res[z=i\pi]
$$
Using $Res[z=i\pi]=-i e^{i \pi a}$ we get
$$
I_1=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi a)}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm a bit confused on how you got $$
I_3=-e^{2\pi a i}I_1$$ and what you mean by "the horizontal parts only differ by phase". Could you please expand on this?

Comment: Try to parametrize $I_3$ correctly then you see what i mean

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the help.